# Chrome mouse events do not work with webkit-transform elements in background

Tags: css, google-chrome, mouseevent

I've got two divs. Page1 has a button ... if you hover over it it will change it's color.

If I add a page2 div in the background with a webkit-transform the button won't change it's color anymore.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page1">
    <button>hover</button>
</div>
<div class="page2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 2;
}
.page2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #999;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.78784, 0, 0.13891, -0.00034, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, -0.17364, 0, 0.9848, -0.00246, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1px;
    background: green;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
}
button:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ89V/1/)

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/y4BVf/

Comment: Should I put that as an answer?

Comment: yes, please add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already stated, the element `.page2` is being rendered in front of the other element because of the `transform` property.

[image]

One way to solve this would be to add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the element in order to prevent it from affecting the other element.

```
.page2 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

As [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> the value 'none' instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tn6S/) - just be aware of `pointer-events`'s [support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events).

An alternative to `pointer-events`, would be to bring the element forward with `translateZ`.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Syt8/)

```
button {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(20px);
}
```